# how the operator overloading works in case of priority_queue?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, c++14, std

```
#define ROW 5 
#define COL 2 

class Person { 

public: 
int age; 

float height; 


 Person(int age, float height) 
    : age(age), height(height) 
{ 
} 
};
```

> How is this operator overloading code responsible for max_Heap??
> if we replace < with > then it results in min_heap how is that working?
> What makes the comparison i.e. p1.height < p2.height at below three lines responsible to give us arrangement for maxHeap implementation.

```
   // we are doing operator overloading through this 
    bool operator<(const Person& p1, const Person& p2) 
    { 
        return p1.height < p2.height; 
    }

int main() 
{ 

priority_queue<Person> Q; 

float arr[ROW][COL] = { { 30, 5.5 }, { 25, 5 },  
           { 20, 6 }, { 33, 6.1 }, { 23, 5.6 } }; 

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) { 

    Q.push(Person(arr[i][0], arr[i][1])); 

    // insert an object in priority_queue by using 
    // the Person class constructor 
} 

while (!Q.empty()) { 

    Person p = Q.top(); 

    Q.pop(); 

    cout << p.age << " " << p.height << "\n"; 
} 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *"how the operator overloading is working"* It's working quite well. I suppose I don't understand the question.

Comment: as we are comparing p1.height & p2.height using < operator and returning either true or false for this comparison, then how its responsible for making the priority_queue to work like a MaxHeap?

Comment: Obviously, `priority_queue` uses this comparison to decide which `Person` instances to order before which other ones. What more do you think would be needed to build a MaxHeap?

Comment: if i would change the operator from < to operator > then also we will get the same effect??

Comment: The question title should be a short summary, while the main question (and a detailed description of your problem and what you're trying to do) should be in the body of the post. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If you reverse the comparison, then naturally you'll end up with elements in reverse order.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it properly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure

Comment: A `priority_queue` (let's call it `Q`) will arrange elements pushed into it in such a way that `Q.top()` is "largest" - meaning that `Q.top() < e` is false for all elements `e` in `Q`. The comparison in `Q.top() < e` could be a built-in less-than operator, or a call to an overloaded `operator<`. In the latter case, the programmer gets to decide which of the two elements should precede the other in the ordering that `Q` uses. Hope this helps.